# What's the difference between A&B and (A)&(B)?

Tags: python

I ran into a weird case:

```
print len(ROI_cord) == 4 
print len(ROI_size) == 2
print len(ROI_cord) == 4 & len(ROI_size) == 2
```

the output is:

```
True
True
False
```

After painful trial and error, I finally found that:

```
print (len(ROI_cord) == 4) & (len(ROI_size) == 2)
```

will give the correct answer.
So here is the question: What's the difference between  A&B and (A&B) on earth? Thanks

Comment: [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence)

Comment: Thanks a lot @NathanHughes and @ Taegyung !

Answer (score 5):

`a == 1 & b == 2` is `a == (1 & b) == 2`

Bitwise AND has higher precedence than equals.

Whereas `and` has lower precedence, consider:

`a == 1 and b == 2` is `(a == 1) and (b == 2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's really an amazing fact to me a new fish :)

Comment: That also explains in my previous code why a == 1 & b == 1 worked well when a=1 and b=1